# calculate the Employee wise date missing (avoid Sat and Sun) in power bi

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have Timekeeping table, in the table 'Date' column contains the employees daily entered time sheet information as how much time they spent for issue by filling hours daily. In my case, i have to find if an employee missed to enter the time sheet for the day, need to show the specific day for Missing day of filling time sheet.  (Not Weekends, Working Day)

can you help how to find out the missing dates in timesheet of the employee!!